# How do reload the mime types after change .desktop file so Files know new app on "Open with" menu

Tags: pantheon-files, app-shortcuts, mimetype

I edited a .desktop (mtPaint) file to add missing mime types it can handle:

```
  MimeType=image/x-targa;image/x-tga;image/x-pcx;image/gif;image/png;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xpm;image/tiff;image/tiff-fx;image/x-ms-bmp;image/jpeg
```

but I don't get File to recognize this App when "Open with" on a file of that type. I tried logoff & login.

Comment: Can you provide more details: which .deskop file and what app? Did you have the problem before editing the .desktop file?

Comment: Added the program name & complete mimeType line

Comment: Also added the %f param to exec. Now I can see the program when displaying All-apps but still not available for all the files with the mime types I added.

Comment: Also add %U to exec

Comment: The problem was I was editing a copy of the .desktop file on my $HOME dir located at ~/.local/share/applications/ . Looks like the global one at /usr/share/applications/ has priority over the personal one.

Comment: With the %U works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was editing a copy of the .desktop file on my $HOME dir located at ~/.local/share/applications/.
Looks like the global one located at /usr/share/applications/ has priority over the personal one. Seems like a bug on pantheon-files to me. The copy at $HOME was created by a GUI menu tool.
The `%U` (or %f ?) at the Exec like is also required.

Comment: FIles relies on system calls to determine which app handles which mime-type so may not be a Files bug. Try rebooting and if it persists then see whether Thunar behaves similarly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update the miminfo.cache using update-desktop-database command.

Comment: Good! The update-desktop-database command shows some syntax errors on my editing. Will try to fix & retry.

Comment: Fixed the error (extra space at the end of line) & rerun the update-desktop-database command but still no menu entry added on Files

Answer (score 1):

Compare the .desktop file of mtpaint with another .desktop file of an app that works and see what's missing or what's different.
You might need to add `%U` at the line `Exec`, so you will have: `Exec=mtpaint %U`